# querySelectorAll vs NodeIterator vs TreeWalker - fastest pure JS flat DOM iterator

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, traversal

I'd like to flatten a DOM tree into an `Array`.
The result should include the root as the first entry.
Plain JS solution is preferred.
What's the fastest way to achieve that?

HTML structure example:

```html
<div class="tested-root">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output expected to be:
`[div.tested-root, span, span, div, span, span, div, span, span]` or alike (this one is DFS, but doesn't really matter for sake of this question).

From the three methods below which is the fastest:

- `querySelectorAll`
- `NodeIterator`
- `TreeWalker`

Comment: Please add a simple HTML tree with the desired array output. And show us what you've tried before.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've came to try another few just recently.
Below the results from slowest to fastest, while specifying how the one slower than the fastest.

> Chrome based results. Safari shows roughly the same numbers. Firefox has issues with that perf app and was not verified.

#### Method 1 (unshift) *~81% slower*

```
const list = Array.from(root.querySelectorAll('*'));
list.unshift(root);
```

#### Method 2 (spread) *~77% slower*

```
const list = [root, ...root.querySelectorAll('*')];
```

#### Method 3 (NodeIterator) *~32% slower*

```js
const list = [];
const ni = document.createNodeIterator(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
let next;
while (next = ni.nextNode()) {
    list.push(next);
}
```

#### Method 4 (TreeWalker) *fastest*

```js
const list = [root];
const tw = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
let next;
while (next = tw.nextNode()) {
    list.push(next);
}
```

#### Bonus (empty root check) *~1% slower (~98% faster for empty root)*

```
const list = [root];
if (root.childElementCount) {
    const tw = document.createTreeWalker(root, NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
    let next;
    while (next = tw.nextNode()) {
        list.push(next);
    }
}
```

#### Observation and conclusions

- array operations, if/when considered, show that spread (`...`) operator way is faster than `unshift` method
- main performance gain comes from using the native iterators, `TreeWalker` being the fastest by far
- it is **almost always** reasonable to implement that special speed-up bonus, for nested structures, the impact is neglectable but for an empty tree it runs **twice** faster

Bench tests can be found [here](https://jsbench.me/91kgrqsrri/1).

Comment: _"Any better ideas?"_ - Why is method 2 exactly the same as the one in your question then?

Comment: For the sake of completeness - comparison assumes at least 2 operands compared, so added it as the base.

Comment: That "comparison" is pointless. This depends on the structure of the document, on the browser, on the version of the browser, on the browser internals, on the program/client that does the measurement, on the hardware that program is running on, ...

Comment: Sorry to say that - but your statement is clearly wrong. ANY comparison depends on those, but GIVEN those are the same and the only different thing is the algo - the algo is compared. This is what we compare here, given the rest is the same.

Comment: Then add all those variables to your "answer"...

Comment: Nope, wrong again - if I'd do an absolute perf metrics, then it would make sense to state that while running on X hardware / Y browser / Z op. system the average result is such and such. This is a best running scenario - so given the same env it will always behave this way.

Comment: On large on large DOM trees (>5k elements), I get drastically better performance (~4 times faster) when using [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator).

Comment: @Yoshi: I'll be updating the answer soon but `NodeIterator` indeed appears to be much faster than the rest - please add an answer to get the kudos!!

Comment: @GullerYA But in your answer you claim in your test `NodeIterator` was found to be ~32% *slower*?

Comment: @Mitya It is slower than TreeWalker - so TreeWalker is the fastest which is most important! NodeIterator is faster than the others (straight forward) ones, there I've agreed with Yoshi. You can actually see it in action in that link where the tests are being running. BTW, even getting the traversed tree ~8K elements has the TreeWalker the fastest one.